# Choice of file management for asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, file-management

I am looking for a free tool for file Management ( like file explorer) for an ASP.net MVC 3 solution ?

which has the requirements

1. Preview capabilities (for images)
2. Creation of folder/files
3. Deletion folder/files
4. Upload capability